# What is the universal command help syntax in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, syntax, command

The only things I know are:

`[switch]` is optional

`[switch1 | switch2]` are both optional, but only one or the other can be used.

What about `{switch}`, or any of the others? I've tried looking online and I can only find PowerShell help syntax, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

---

To clear up any confusing, im not talking about a specific command in partiular, im just asking about how all command help pages are written.hope that makes sence

Comment: What documentation are you reading?

Comment: @lit I was referring to windows commands, i.e. if you type `copy/?`, it shows the code syntax. im not sure what switches in `{`s mean, as well as others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it. wasnt sure how to look it up but i found it.

here, if anyone else need it: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-read-command-syntax-2618082

scroll down 2 the tabel at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Corporation describes the help syntax.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490917.aspx